# Convert domain date to java util date

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, date-conversion, java.util.date

I have tried to convert a domain date to java util date but it's failed.
I am using the method to do the conversion:

```
public static java.util.Date convertDomainDateToUtilDate(oracle.jbo.domain.Date domainDate) {
java.util.Date date = null;
if (domainDate != null) {
java.sql.Date sqldate = domainDate.dateValue();
date = new Date(sqldate.getTime());
}
return date;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert domainDate to java util Date ? Is it because of a Date value in a View Object ? If so, you could simply change the definition of your View Object to be directly set as a java util Date instead of a domain date

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: *it's failed* — that’s very vague and far from enough to help you. Please specify exactly what result you have expected, best with an example, and how observed result differs. If you are seeing any error message, quote it verbatim in the question.

Comment: Hi MrAdibou, I believe what you mean is to change the data type in view object? if yes then I am not advised to do that because it will affect other area that is using it and I need to change the type in SQL developer if i wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getValue` to get the right type directly

```
public static java.util.Date convertDomainDateToUtilDate(oracle.jbo.domain.Date domainDate) {
    if (domainDate != null) {
        return domainDate.getValue();
    }
    return null;
}
```

or if you want to move to Java 8 LocalDate

```
 public static LocalDate convertDomainDateToUtilDate(oracle.jbo.domain.Date domainDate) {
    if (domainDate != null) {
        return domainDate.getValue().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    }
    return null;
}
```

After a recommendation from @OleV.V, you can also get `LocalDate` from java.sql.Date

```
public static LocalDate convertDomainDateToUtilDate(oracle.jbo.domain.Date domainDate) {
    if (domainDate != null) {
        return domainDate.dateValue().toLocalDate();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @OleV.V. yes but I only considered util.Date and didn't bother with sql.Date, strange that only sql.Date has this method . Thanks for the input.

Comment: It makes some sense since `java.sql.Date` was supposed to be used with an SQL `date`, which (in standard SQL) is a date without time of day, like `LocalDate`. Still not sure what the asker’s real issue was and whether your suggestions (or mine) solve it.